# Trying to create onclick event in node js grid using KOGrid

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, grid, kogrid

I would like to have a nice interactive grid view in an HTML page.  I am using nodejs, express, twitterbootstrap, knockoutjs, for my technology stack.  I am trying to use KOGrid to display various data points with some nice built in column sorting and other grid functionality.

My issue is trying to fire an event when a button is clicked in a row.  And pass to that event, some of the various data fields from that specific row.  So in KOGrid specifics, I am using cellTemplates and I need to call some function in the onclick event, but pass that function some KOGRID data bounded values.  So, in my input element I would have
data-bind="onclick: [Name of my function]( [name of some data bounded variable], [name of some other data bounded variable])

Can someone show me how to do this?

Here is a sample of my code...the input/onclick in the CBTemplate is where I am having issues.

CBTEMPLATE:

```
<script type="text/html" id="actionTemplate">
<div data-bind="kgCell: $cell">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox" checked="checked" data-bind="onclick: 'MyOnClickFunction( siteId(), status() )'"/>
</div>
</script>
```

DIV TAG:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: offer.siteCounts,
                    columnDefs: [ { field: 'templateField0', displayName: 'Site', cellTemplate: 'siteTemplate', width: 150},
                                 { field: 'status', displayName: 'Current Status', cellClass: 'site', cellTemplate: 'statusTemplate', width: 115},
                                 { field: 'details', displayName: 'Details', width: 175},
                                 { field: 'actionField0', displayName: 'Action', cellTemplate: 'cbTemplate', width: 200}],
                    autogenerateColumns: false,
                    displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
                    isMultiSelect: false }">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [click event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) should look like this with KO:

```
data-bind="click: function(data,event) { MyOnClickFunction(siteId(), status()) }"
```

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/ttBCQ/1/) where you can play with it.

Some sidenotes:

- In my sample I have used the `$root` [binding context property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) to access the sample function:  `$root.offer.MyOnClickFunction`. You will need to adjust this depending on which level you have defined the `MyOnClickFunction` on your viewmodels.
- You need to `return true` from the click binding handler if you do want to let the default click action proceed (e.g checking the checkbox etc.)